# Flow path from a point

Tags: qgis, flow

Are there any tools in the QGIS Processing Toolbox that allow calculation of flow path and distance from a point on a roadway?

I have made a depressionless DEM (geotiff).
I'm analyzing runoff from a road and want to know where it goes to.

I'm using QGIS version 3.28.2-Firenze

Comment: There is likely something you can use in the [WhiteBox tools](https://www.whiteboxgeo.com/manual/wbt_book/intro.html) plugin.